# Is there a way to turn on wifi on iphone through your app's code?

Tags: wifi, ios4

I am building an app using iPhone SDK 4. Is there a way to programmatically turn on the Wifi on an iPhone/iPodTouch (iOS 4 specifically) if it is switched off ? I want to be able to turn on Wifi (if its turned off) after alerting the user and taking his/her decision into account.

Thanks,
Abhinav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't override the user's settings for the device itself.

You can set the app to require Wifi by putting the `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` key into the apps Info.plist file. This will evoke a system dialog asking the user to activate WiFi if it is not available.

Comment: Thanks ! pretty much what I was looking for, as I also had the notion that you could not force a setting on to the user.